# What do you say on bullying documentation if you don't know the exact date of the incident?

Tags: human-resources, bullying, documentation

If you are writing a bullying report for HR but you only have a vague idea of when the incident happened e.g. Early in March what do you say? Do you say that you don't know when? Or explain why you didn't write it down?

I feel like this is murky territory.

I mean you don't usually write down stuff that someone walks up to you and out of the blue says.

Comment: Be aware that the typical reaction from HR is to treat you like an outsider and to protect the offender. This is because if guilt is determined on the part of the offender, it's only a short step to guilt being placed on the employer. Last time I reported extreme abuse (refusing breaks, blackmail etc), they actually gave the offender a free paid 2 week vacation during a no vacation time (very busy season) just to delay having to take action against him. This bought them a two week window to **deal with me**, not him. Watch your back, no one else is.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire This isn't the OP's first time asking these questions. Based on the many other complaints posted here, I'm guessing it's a question of when he/she will be let go of. I'm a bit surprised they let it drag out this long, though. They must be a very tolerant company. At this point the OP can only go to a lawyer, not HR for action to be taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you are writing a bullying report for HR but you only have a vague
>   idea of when the incident happened e.g. Early in March what do you
>   say?

You say it happened "early in March". (You really shouldn't just make up a date)

> Do you say that you don't know when?

You could, but since you do know it was early in March, you can do better.

> Or explain why you didn't write it down?
>
> I mean you don't usually write down stuff that someone walks up to you
>   and out of the blue says.

You probably don't need to explain why you didn't do something unless you are asked why.

You really need to consult your lawyer first if you are trying to build a case. Otherwise, when you aren't sure what to write - ask HR how specific your answers on their report need to be.

Answer (score 2):

When people are testifying under oath in court, they often use the phrase "On or around March 5th." Obviously, substitute March 5th for your best guess.

If that's good enough for a court of law it should be sufficient for HR.

Usual disclaimer - I am not a lawyer. If you want legal advice, consult a professional.